# Force refresh of .html in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I´m executing my .html file on a local server and I think that the .html file gets cached by my browser. I need to change *something* in my .html so my browser will reload the .html (which is, as you can imagine trying out new code, meeeehhh...)

Is there an easy way to force a refresh of the .html file every time I reload the page and/or clear the cache for this specific site?

Things like "?n=1" wont work, it will work once, until its get cached...

Comment: Sounds very much like an X/Y problem. Since we cannot see the code that gives you problems, and assuming you do need to refresh (unlikely) then try `"?rnd="+new Date().getTime()`

Comment: The caching is with the server. Please provide more information about your local server; What type of server is it, how is it configured, etc?

Comment: "I need to change something in my .html" — No, not with the HTML, with the server. The specifics will depend on which server you use. The general case is explained here: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: If you are just developing, Your developer tools have the ability to fetch with no cache on every request.

Comment: m using a WAMP server with the standard config.